# How to call Perl constructor from Bash?

Tags: perl, bash

I have a file in perl that has a constructor

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package ConfigFileReader;

sub new {
    my ($mode, $configFileName) = @ARGV;

    print $mode;
    print $configFileName;
}
```

I know that passing a parameter to a perl script is like

```
helloworld.pl arg1 arg2 argN
```

Now, how can I call the constructor new{} from the command line? BTW I am calling the perl file in a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

x=`helloworld.pl arg1 arg2 argN`;

echo $x;
```

Comment: Why is the constructor referring to `@ARGV`?  By nearly universal convention, it should simply receive the arguments from `@_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG1=...
ARG2=...

X=`perl -e "use ConfigFileReader; new ConfigFileReader($ARG1,$ARG2);"`

echo $X
```

Comment: Wait, what if i want to specify the path of the script? I tried perl -e helloworld.pl "Use ConfigFileReader; new ConfigFileReader("arg1", "arg2", "arg2");" but nothing happened.

Comment: I expect that when you create package 'ConfigFileReader' it is in MODULE ConfigFileReader.pm
Then you can specify the path to that module with:
`perl -Ipath_to_dir_containing_module -e "..."`

Comment: No, you would add this code to `helloworld.pl` or replace it with an in-place script.  Perhaps something like `perl -MConfigFileReader -e 'newConfigFileReader($ARGV[0],$ARGV[1]) && require "helloworld.pl"' arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 0):

You can call new within your perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package ConfigFileReader;

sub new {
    my ($mode, $configFileName) = @ARGV;

    print $mode;
    print $configFileName;
}

my $cfg = new ConfigFileReader(@ARGV); # call new with arguments
```